# Changing Format of column in Data grid view

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridviewcolumn

I have a data grid view that I am populating with a database as its data source. However, the columns with a date as its data type show a date and time while I only want a time.

How do I change the format of a data grid view table?

```
Private Sub prcDisplayTable()
    dgvViewLecturers.DataSource = Nothing
    dgvViewLecturers.Rows.Clear()
    dgvViewLecturers.Columns.Clear()

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Lecturers"
    strTableName = "ViewLecturers"

    daLecturers = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, con)
    daLecturers.Fill(dsLecturers, strTableName)

    dgvViewLecturers.DataSource = dsLecturers
    dgvViewLecturers.DataMember = strTableName
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for time only format

```
dataGridView1.Columns("dateColumn").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "hh:mm:ss tt";
```

Answer (score 0):

Set [DefaultCellStyle.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format.aspx) property.

```
 dataGridView1.Columns("dateColumn").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "hh:mm:ss t";
```